# Remove Footer from url into Webview using JSoap

Tags: android, html, android-webview, jsoup

I am using J soap library for removing footer in web view.
but there is a problem when we load data to web view.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]when data show in web view then some css is missing in this.
I am sending you the code and snapshot of web view.
check it and give me the solution.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String url="http://stackoverflow.com/";
    private Document doc;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Log.e("HEEEEEEEEEEEEE", doc + "");

            Element footer = doc.getElementById("footer");
            Log.e("BY IDDDD", footer + "");
            footer.remove();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Load data into a WebView
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //wv.loadUrl(url);
        wv.loadData(doc.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer resolve the issue? If so, please accept it, otherwise please post a follow up question/clarification as comment to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

By loading the page content without reference to the original base-url, relative paths are broken.

**Fix**

Replace

```
wv.loadData(doc.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

with

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, doc.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

> **loadDataWithBaseURL**
>
> Loads the given data into this WebView, using baseUrl as the base URL
>   for the content. The base URL is used both to resolve relative URLs
>   and when applying JavaScript's same origin policy. The historyUrl is
>   used for the history entry.

See: [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))